# combining 2 MATLAB structs

Tags: matlab

I have two small structures that I would like to combine but I can't find the right solution. Struct A and B have one column in common (same string values), although it is important that the common values are not necessarily in the same order between the two. For the sake of example, I put them in a different order. I would like to achieve what is in struct C below, where the info from both structures are organised together:

```
A(1).condition = 'con1';
A(1).y = rand(10, 1);
A(2).condition = 'con2';
A(2).y = rand(10, 1);

B(1).condition = 'con2';
B(1).z = normrnd(0,1);
B(2).condition = 'con1';
B(2).z = normrnd(0,1);

% Desired output:
C = A;
C(1).z = B(2).z;
C(2).z = B(1).z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

1. Find the order in which the elements of one struct array match the other, based on the value of `condition`.
2. Copy each field in `B(i)` to the corresponding element of array `A`. I'm assuming there are more fields in `B` than just `z` and `condition`.

Step 1 can be accomplished using [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html), whose second output argument gives the indices into one array matching elements in the other. We're assuming that each element of `B` has a matching element in `A`:

```
[~,I] = ismember({A.condition},{B.condition});
```

Note that `{A.condition}` is a cell array with all the `condition` strings. `B(I)` is the struct array `B` reordered to match `A`.

Step 2 can be accomplished as in [rahnema1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55193234/7328782), which we generalize here to copy multiple fields using a loop over the field names, and using [dynamic field names](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html):

```
fields = fieldnames(B);
fields = setdiff(fields,'condition'); % don't copy over this field
for ii = 1:numel(fields)
   [A.(fields{ii})] = B(I).(fields{ii});
end
```

---

Testing:

```
A(1).condition = 'con1';
A(1).y = [1,1,1];
A(2).condition = 'con2';
A(2).y = [2,2];
A(3).condition = 'con3';
A(3).y = [3,3,3];

B(1).condition = 'con2';
B(1).z = 2;
B(1).x = 'b';
B(2).condition = 'con3';
B(2).z = 3;
B(2).x = 'c';
B(3).condition = 'con1';
B(3).z = 1;
B(3).x = 'a';

[~,I] = ismember({A.condition},{B.condition});

fields = fieldnames(B);
fields = setdiff(fields,'condition'); % don't copy over this field
for ii = 1:numel(fields)
   [A.(fields{ii})] = B(I).(fields{ii});
end
```

This yields the following struct `A`:

```
>> A(1)

ans = 

  struct with fields:

    condition: 'con1'
            y: [1 1 1]
            x: 'a'
            z: 1

>> A(2)

ans = 

  struct with fields:

    condition: 'con2'
            y: [2 2]
            x: 'b'
            z: 2

>> A(3)

ans = 

  struct with fields:

    condition: 'con3'
            y: [3 3 3]
            x: 'c'
            z: 3
```

Comment: After reading your answer I understood what OP actually wants.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a [`comma separated list`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) to another comma separated list:

```
C = A;
[C(2:-1:1).z] = B.z;
```

or

```
[C.z] = B(2:-1:1).z;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not elegant, but it should work:

```
C = A
for idx_A = 1:length(A)
    for idx_B = 1:length(B)
        if strcmp(A(idx_A).condition, B(idx_B).condition)
            C(idx_A).z = B(idx_B).z
        end
    end
end
```

If you need frequent merging operations, you could consider using [tables](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html). If you want to stick to structs, I think it is generally advisable to use structs of arrays instead of arrays of structs, like so:

```
A.condition = {'con1', 'con2'};
A.y = [rand(10, 1), rand(10, 1)]
```

That makes many operations easier.